# Apply a function along all elements in a array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have some array:

```
array = np.array([[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]])
```

I want to calculate [np.kron](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) in a such manner:

```
def func(array):
    res = array[0]
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        res = np.kron(res, array[i]) 
    return res
```

But how to do it in a more numpy way?

I tried [np.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
res = np.apply_along_axis(np.kron, 1, array)
```

But I didn't succeed.

Comment: How exactly do you want to the output be like?

Comment: @Soften98 tensor(kroneker) product of all vectors of array.

Comment: So, something like `kron(kron(kron(kron(a[0], a[1]), a[2]), a[3]), a[4])`?

Comment: @Alfe yes, exactly what I want!

Comment: I fear this isn't possible (yet).  `numpy`'s way of doing this is via `numpy.ufunc.reduce` or `numpy.ufunc.accumulate`, also reachable e. g. via `numpy.add.accumulate`, etc.  Unfortunately the `kron` function isn't implemented as `ufunc` and thus cannot be used in these.  There is no reason I know of why it cannot be implemented as such, so I guess in later versions (maybe yours is younger than mine?) of `numpy` it might be possible.  Up to then @slashCoder's solution is the best I can think of.

Comment: Coming to think of it, given the nature of the `kron` function, I don't think that `numpy` could optimize very much in this case, even if it did the reducing step itself.  `kron` mostly bloats up the memory, it doesn't compute very much which could be optimized.

Comment: @Alfe okey, I've accepted `reduce` answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's more "numpy",  but a definitely more pythonic way would be to use the reduce built-in function:

```
reduce(np.kron, array)
```

Comment: Yep, task understood and provided a working pure-Python solution.  But the evaluation done this way will be not optimized.  If there is a numpy-variant to express exactly this, it will be way faster.

Comment: Btw, since Python3 you need to `from functools import reduce`.